# How to read xml directly from URLs with scrapy/python

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, scrapy

In Scrapy you will have to define `start_url`s. But how can I crawl from other urls as well?

Up to now I have a login script which logs into a webpage. After logging in, I want to extract xml from different urls.

```
import scrapy

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    start_urls = ['login page']
    urls = ['url','url']

def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'UserName': '', 'Password': ''},
        callback=self.check_login_response
    )

def check_login_response(self, response):
    # check login succeed before going on
    if "incorrect" in response.body:
        self.log("Login failed", level=scrapy.log.ERROR)
        return
```

How is it possible to crawl data from the urls defined in the urls array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `yield` [`Request`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) instances to the other URLs:

```
def check_login_response(self, response):
    # check login succeed before going on
    if "incorrect" in response.body:
        self.log("Login failed", level=scrapy.log.ERROR)
        return

    for url in list_or_urls:
        yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_other_url)

def parse_other_url(self, response):
    # ...
```

Comment: By the way, is it possible that .xpath() doesn't recognize all xpath's? Because I try to scrape information from a website, but for some reason I can't extract data from some divs/tables (i'm using firebug for copying xpath)

Comment: @user2237168 there could be multiple reasons for that. One is that the DOM is formed by javascript being executed in the browser. If you need help with the problem, consider making a separate question. Thanks.